# OG Pic display on FB not showing full preview on android phones

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I just made a new website for my photography business. I selected a feature image for OG to show when i share on social sites like FB.

The pic and title and desc are showing properly and full preview on FB when viewing through larger screens and iPhone. When i look at it on Note 5 or Note 9 the OG preview is not full preview and shows as thumbnail.

Funny thing is my friend's similar website if i post on fb and watch it through my phone it shows full preview. I am not sure where and what to looks and what to do.

On whatsapp it also shows thumbnail which i think is how it's supposed to be.

I am using wordpress for the site and Yoast for the OG.

I have tried resizing images and stuff but no luck. Do i need to change some code for it?

where would i find the code to show here as i am not sure where in theme editor it will be

Comment: Try following the recommendation for an image aspect ratio of 1.91:1, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images There isn’t much more you can do, in the end Facebook decides how to display this - and it can even differ for two people looking at the same shared link sometimes.

Comment: i tried the ratio thing as well ... problem is that it shows different in android phones and show full preview in apple phones while on bigger screen it is fine and shows full preview as well as apple phones.. is there a code we can use to define height and width which will show full preview pic no matter what phone or device it is seen on... ?

Comment: No, not really. Other then specifying an image that follows their guidelines, not much you can do.

Comment: so how come i can see my friend website in the same profession with using Yoast as well shows up with full preview on my phone. Isnt that bit odd. what do you think could it be a theme issue or like u said just FB being FB..